# Send_keys() not working in chrome through selenium python for inserting integer value on website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python and selenium and wanted some help in this area. Below is the table on the website:

[image]

I am trying to insert a value against the product through the selenium web driver on the HTML table through the send_keys command.

I want to insert the quantities against the product. I have tried this but not working.

```
button =WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*text()='Arrow Shirts']/following-sibling::td[1]")))

button.click()

time.sleep(10)

button.send_keys('3')
```

I am getting error:

```
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

How to get this and insert the value?

Xpath for the qty:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PRODUCTS$ctl02$tbox" type="text" maxlength="4" id="ContentPlaceHolder1">
```

Comment: I assume you're actually looking for an `<input>` element inside the `<td>` .

Comment: What's the url of the page you're trying to interact with?

Comment: yes it has input element what needs to be done next. URL is restricted to specific users

Comment: You would need to adjust the xpath so that it finds the input element, not the td.

Comment: Thanks, John...It's Working Now...Tried using input element